# Remove a language from the language bar in WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, language, input-languages, control-panel, language-bar

In the language bar I have a "Dutch" language that I don't need and never use, hence I want to remove it. Here's a pictures of the language bar with the Dutch option:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF4Ri.png]

The first thing I've tried is going to `Control Panel > Time & Language > Region & Language` and looking for any Dutch languages installed, but there are none installed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE1so.png]

Next, I went to `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language` to see if there are any Dutch languages installed, but still no luck:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQo3T.png]

The only Dutch program I have installed is an Microsoft Office Dutch Language Pack. Does that have to do with it? Is there any possible way to remove this language from the language bar? Thanks.

Edit: when I click on settings

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQo3T.png]

I also see just one language:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkBRU.png]

Comment: @Ramhound Oh wow that actually did the trick. I added the language > installed the language (from Windows Update) > added the keyboards and then removed the keyboard + language and it's gone! Thank you very much. Is it possible to mark this comment as solution? Or do you have to submit a new answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard language keeps changing in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/976947/keyboard-language-keeps-changing-in-windows-10)

Comment: JimmyDG, @Ramhound, I have *exactly* the same problem. I tried following JimmyDG's suggestion, but I might have misunderstood the procedure. I clicked on the small "ENG" button near the bottom-right corner; "Language preferences" popped up, clicked on those; added Dutch; removed Dutch; checked the effect -- indeed Dutch was gone. But it only worked until I restarted Windows. Then Dutch was back in its place. How can I get rid of it permanently? The answer by xpy seems interesting, but I am afraid to experiment with the registry, and I do not quite understand what exactly I should do there.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for a quick response. Well, just for the record, it did not work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 11):

To solve the language keep adding itself issue follow these steps:

1. go to **Control Panel** -> **Language**
2. from the sidebar select "**Change date, time, or number formats**"
3. select "**Administrative**" tab.
4. in the "**Welcome screen and new user accounts**" box click "**Copy settings**.." button
5. Check the two boxes under "**Copy your current settings to**"
6. the windows will ask you to restart the computer then you finish :)

the original answer from [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/english-us-keeps-appearing-as-an-input-language/c8f13289-1736-4a8a-9f5f-78631f23e67a)

Comment: Oh of course.  So obvious in retrospect!  <rolling eyes>

Comment: That solved it, thx! Something really wrong is going on with windows in the last couple of versions...

Comment: even though this answer is really old, you made my day!

Comment: @Mogi I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 6):

I found an answer that solved the problem for me.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/desktop/my-keyboard-layout-is-switching-automatically-by/98eda57a-c225-45b2-a233-42f21fadb0cd

The only step I did was to go to the registry, to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language\Default`and change the `REG_SZ` value to the language I wanted.

[here is a list of all the language codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx)

Comment: I tried changing the default value but got a message "Cannot edit Default: Error writing the value's new contents". Do I have insufficient permission (I am not the ultimate administrator)? Also, there is a field `(Default)` with value `(value not set)`. Does that one matter?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem in a swiss environment. My language settings listed only two languages: swiss german and russian, which I also wanted to have. But the language box in the task panel listed 4 languages: swiss german, standard german, swiss french and russian.

I have found the solution for me in a pretty old posting blogspot post: http://botsikas.blogspot.com/2010/02/unwanted-languages-in-language-bar.html

What I basically needed to do is to remove unwanted languages from Microsoft Office Language Settings.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem: lots of languages in language bar (each added when I installed different language versions of a software), yet only two listed in the Control Panel - so I couldn't remove them from there.

The solution: 
1. remove the language-version software that you no longer need
2. RESTART THE COMPUTER. This does wonders.