# window 10 'invisible' language

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

After installing windows 10, my main input language became "UK English Keyboard" instead of "US English Keyboard".
I Added the selected keyboard and removed the undesired one.
After rebooting my PC, the UK Keyboard made an invisible comeback, so i can't see it in my language list, but it can be used when switching languages with alt+shift.

[image: You can see the issue here]

I want to remove this extra language from my input methods, so when i press alt+shift i will have only the US Keyboard. i don't need the same language twice, and i don't want the UK keyboard which gives me irregular chars (for example " instead of @). Because this keyboard is not my editable list, i can't remove it so my question is how i remove a 'nonexistent' language.

Comment: To quote him  from an edit he is trying to put through "Well, lets make it clear. I want to remove this extra language from my input methods, so when i press alt+shift i will have only the US Keyboard. i don't need the same language twice, and i don't want the UK keyboard which gives me irregular chars (for example " instead of @). Because this keyboard is not my editable list, i can't remove it so my question is how i remove a 'nonexistent' language."

Comment: I believe you tried to edit the question. See [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) Merge the accounts, then you will be able to edit freely because you will own the question.

Comment: you're asking about removing a language from the language bar, the question has been asked here but I don't see a good answer https://superuser.com/questions/994389/remove-a-language-from-the-language-bar-in-windows-10

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  I'm not sure who tried to put the edit through. I approved it but it needed further approval.  He posted an answer with the edit then removed that answer.. and I see the edit put through by LPChip, i'm not sure who requested the edit

Comment: @barlop And I rejected the edit because I'm not sure if it's the same person. If it's the OP who edited then he should merge the accounts first, then do a legitimate edit as the question owner. This seems to be the right way.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  Notice that a person called "serg90"  posted an "answer" speaking as the questioner explaining what he was asking. And you rejected the edit because you think serg90 might not be the same person as Sergey.  Do you seriously think that it's a weird coincidence that they just so happen to have their name start with Serg and that they talk as if they are the same person or as if they are only pretending to be the same person?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski if you think they are different people then I think you are too much of a conspiracy theorist even for alex jones and david icke.. next you will be accusing people of being lizards(like david icke does).  You should not have rejected that edit as it clarified the question and is clearly his clarification and nobody elses.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I'd tend to lean on the side of accepting the suggested edit. Also, be sure to point them to the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) so that the OP can get the accounts merged.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instruction:

- Click Language Preferences
- Select Additional date -> time & regional settings
- Change Input method
- Try add the language you want to remove, and remove it again.

and also change the Windows registry key as [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/483086/how-do-i-remove-automatically-added-keyboard-layouts).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with another language and almost tore all of my hair out trying many different suggested solutions until I finally found the solution that worked for me.

The problem (for me) was that the user interface design of the Windows 10 PC Settings is really bad in this case.

First, in the PC Settings Region and Language, click "English (United States)", even though you don't want to remove the "English (United States)" keyboard layout. (This is where the bad interface design is – why would you look there for "United Kingdom" if it says "United States"?)

[image]

Then click Options. I can only send you a Danish screenshot to illustrate, as my Windows is in Danish, but it can likely be understood anyway:

[image]

Now you will see that there is in fact a United Kingdom layout there under "Keyboards" (again, my screenshot differs, but the point is the same; actual screenshots from an English Windows are welcome as replacements).

[image]

Click the keyboard you don't want, in this case likely "United Kingdom", and then click Remove.

[image]

That's it. No need to restart or anything. The unwanted layout is gone.

Of course I can't say if this will help you, but it sure did help me.

And sorry for the messy answer with screenshots in Danish. I hope it can be understood anyway. It would likely take me 45 minutes more to switch the interface language of Windows to English, add the exact same keyboard layouts as you had, take the screenshots, and then change everything back again afterwards, and then I likely wouldn't have written this at all. Please forgive me.