# How to stop Windows 10 switching keyboard layout to default language after sleep

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

How can I stop Windows 10 from switching input language automatically?

It does it when my laptop goes to sleep. On wake up it will switch the keyboard input language to the default language. I don't want this. When I choose an input language, I do so for a reason. I don't need it switched by the OS.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rant/comments/8z57g8/why_is_windows_10_such_a_fucking_piece_of_shit/

Comment: I don't use Windows but that sounds like a bug.

Comment: There is a similar thread, try to check the answer and test on your side. https://superuser.com/questions/976947/keyboard-language-keeps-changing-in-windows-10